# How to get data from SQL after using the like statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query

```
SELECT 
    ap.id, ap.text,
    p.id AS uId, p.points, p.text AS up 
FROM 
    `phrases` AS ap 
LEFT JOIN 
    `phrases` AS p ON p.createdBy = 1 
WHERE 
    ap.createdBy = 0  
    AND (ap.text LIKE CONCAT('%', p.text, '%')
         OR p.text LIKE CONCAT('%', ap.text, '%'))
```

I get the data like this:

[image: i get the data like this]

But I also want all the data that did not match as null from ap table

Comment: what is your join key between two tables not clear in your question and which column is null that also not clear so please clear those things in your question

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You should explain the logic you want implemented.  And provide a database tag.

Comment: I am joining the same table - first using the createdBy= 1 and then CreatedBy =0 keys. No column is null but i want to retrive all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want matches all phrases where `createdby = 1` and matching phrases that contain the text.  If so:

```
SELECT ap.id, ap.text, p.id as uId, p.points,
p.text as up 
FROM `phrases` ap LEFT JOIN
     `phrases` p
     ON p.createdBy = 1 AND
        (p.text LIKE concat('%', ap.text,'%') or
         p.ap.createdBy = 0 
        )
WHERE ap.createdBy = 0 ;
```

Comment: Thank you this works but i want to show all the phrases where createdby = 1 and your solutions shows where createdby = 0. Can you please help?

Comment: @AbhijitSood . . . I modified the answer.